# FlashDevelop class with static method

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

When I type a class name without `new` before, FlashDevelop does not show autocompleate. Is it a way to enable that feature? (do you have the same issue?)

Comment: Which version of FlashDevelop? I don't have this issue with FD3 or FD4.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature because FlashDevelop cannot guess what you want to type when there's no `new` keyword. Press Ctrl + Space, if you want display the autocomplete dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I either type "new" before the class and then delete it, or I type the class name, and then do Ctrl-Shift-1 on it so it gets included.